# Is there a way to RUN AS admin with IE7?

Tags: administrator, internet-explorer-7

I tried to remote in a person's computer and login as an administrator but I still could not see the control panel due to the way our group policy is. So just wanted to know if there is a way to open IE7 as an administrator.

Comment: Any chance you could tell us the operating system of the target machine? Workarounds vary. A useful article to read would be this one:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/06/28/and-so-this-is-vista.aspx (= http://tinyurl.com/3akygnp )

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the IE 7 icon and click `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: Unless you meant Windows XP, in which case this answer is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a weird problem where the Network Connections tab was just randomly disabled after Internet Explorer was started up one morning.

This support article helped me out:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272449